# There are multiple properties indexed against the same field name ..., but with different indexing settings. The behaviour is undefined

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search

Getting the following in my log when I run my Hibernate Search application:

`WARN 23 Jun 2014 15:08:51,623 org.hibernate.search.engine.metadata.impl.TypeMetadata:339 - HSEARCH000120: There are multiple properties indexed against the same field name 'foo.bar', but with different indexing settings. The behaviour is undefined.`

I see that the warning is being logged from:

```
private Map<String, DocumentFieldMetadata> keyFieldMetadata(Set<PropertyMetadata> propertyMetadataSet) {
    Map<String, DocumentFieldMetadata> tmpMap = new HashMap<String, DocumentFieldMetadata>();
    for ( PropertyMetadata propertyMetadata : propertyMetadataSet ) {
        for ( DocumentFieldMetadata documentFieldMetadata : propertyMetadata.getFieldMetadata() ) {
            DocumentFieldMetadata oldFieldMetadata = tmpMap.put(
                    documentFieldMetadata.getName(),
                    documentFieldMetadata
            );
            if ( oldFieldMetadata != null ) {
                if ( !documentFieldMetadata.getIndex().equals( oldFieldMetadata.getIndex() ) ) {
                    **log.inconsistentFieldConfiguration( documentFieldMetadata.getName()** );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for ( DocumentFieldMetadata documentFieldMetadata : classBridgeFields ) {
        tmpMap.put( documentFieldMetadata.getName(), documentFieldMetadata );
    }

    if ( idPropertyMetadata != null ) {
        for ( DocumentFieldMetadata documentFieldMetadata : idPropertyMetadata.getFieldMetadata() ) {
            tmpMap.put( documentFieldMetadata.getName(), documentFieldMetadata );
        }
    }
    return Collections.unmodifiableMap( tmpMap );
}
```

but I'm having trouble figuring out the purpose of this code, or how my code could be causing it to meet the condition. It appears to only be happening on fields annotated with `@IndexedEmbedded` I've Googled and found nothing for the error.

I assume that this has always been an issue in the code, but I just recently updated from Hibernate Search 4.2.0.Final to 4.5.1.Final, and this is when the warning began to appear.

**UPDATE**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "data_providers")
@Immutable
@Embeddable
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
public class EDataProvider {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = -4207808146855081627L;

   public static final String FIELD_ASSOCIATIONS = "associations.";

   public static final String FIELD_ID = "id";

   private List<EDataProvider> associatedProviders;

   private Long id;

   private boolean isInternal;

   private String name;

   private Float priority;

   public EDataProvider() {

      this(null, null);
   }

   /**
    * @param name
    * @param id
    */
   public EDataProvider(final String name, final Long id) {

      super();
      this.name = name;
      this.id = id;
      associatedProviders = new Vector<EDataProvider>();
   }

   /**
    * @param newProvider
    */
   public void addAssociatedProvider(final EDataProvider newProvider) {

      associatedProviders.add(newProvider);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(final Object obj) {

      if (this == obj) {
         return true;
      }
      if ((obj == null) || !(obj instanceof EDataProvider)) {
         return false;
      }
      final EDataProvider other = (EDataProvider) obj;
      if (!ObjectUtil.equals(getId(), other.getId())) {
         return false;
      }
      return true;
   }

   @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
               cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
   @JoinTable(name = "data_provider_associations",
              joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id") },
              inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "child_id") })
   @IndexedEmbedded(depth = 1,
                    prefix = FIELD_ASSOCIATIONS)
   @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
   public List<EDataProvider> getAssociatedProviders() {

      return associatedProviders;
   }

   @Id
   @Column(name = "id")
   @Field(name = FIELD_ID)
   public Long getId() {

      return id;
   }

   @Column(name = "name")
   public String getName() {

      return name;
   }

   @Column(name = "boost")
   public Float getPriority() {

      return priority;
   }

   @Override
   public int hashCode() {

      return EncodingUtil.makeHashCode(31, getId());
   }

   @Column(name = "internal")
   public boolean isInternal() {

      return isInternal;
   }

   public void removeAssociatedProvider(final EDataProvider newProvider) {

      associatedProviders.remove(newProvider);
   }

   /**
    * @param newAssociatedProviders
    *           the associatedProviders to set
    */
   public void setAssociatedProviders(
         final List<EDataProvider> newAssociatedProviders) {

      associatedProviders = newAssociatedProviders;
   }

   /**
    * @param dataProviderId
    *           the dataProviderId to set
    */
   public void setId(final Long dataProviderId) {

      id = dataProviderId;
   }

   public void setInternal(final boolean isInternal) {

      this.isInternal = isInternal;
   }

   /**
    * @param name
    *           the name to set
    */
   public void setName(final String name) {

      this.name = name;
   }

   /**
    * @param priority
    *           the priority to set
    */
   public void setPriority(final Float priority) {

      this.priority = priority;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {

      return String.format("provider:{id:%d, name:%s, priority:%f}", id, name,
            priority);
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your entity configuration? Do you have multiple properties indexed against the same Lucene Document field?

Comment: @Hardy I posted the entity above; however, I believe I've found the suspect. The ID field was annotated in the child object with a `@Field` annotation as well as included in the parent object's index. The parent object uses a custom analyzer, so there was a conflict in the indexing settings. As soon as I removed the `@Field` annotation from the child object, the errors went away. Does this sound like a correct assumption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ID field was annotated in the child object with a @Field annotation as well as included in the parent object's index. The parent object uses a custom analyzer, so there was a conflict in the indexing settings. As soon as I removed the @Field annotation from the child object, the errors went away.